# XSL FO get image from server

Tags: spring, xslt, apache-fop

Im using FOP version 2.1. I have a xsl fo template where i want to show images:

```
 <xsl:variable name="ImagePath" select="defaultImageUrl"/>
 <fo:external-graphic src="{$ImagePath}" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" width="100%"/>
```

Some images have a webadress like so:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Tulipa_biflora_UME.jpg/800px-Tulipa_biflora_UME.jpg
```

But other images come from my webserver from address like:

```
https://localhost:4200/api/download/image/?fixedPrice=true&amp;productId=1329&amp;fileId=1304
```

This responds to endpoint:

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFileAsResponseEntity(@RequestParam boolean fixedPrice, @RequestParam long productId, @RequestParam long fileId) throws IOException, SQLException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    FileDownload fileDownload = productService.getProductFile(productId, fileId, fixedPrice);
    headers.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());
    String n = fileDownload.getFileName().toLowerCase();
    if (fileDownload.getFileTypeEnum().equals(FileTypeEnum.PICTURE) && (n.contains(".jpeg") || n.contains("jpg"))) {
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    } else if (fileDownload.getFileTypeEnum().equals(FileTypeEnum.PICTURE) && (n.contains(".png"))) {
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
    } else if (fileDownload.getFileTypeEnum().equals(FileTypeEnum.PICTURE) && (n.contains(".gif"))) {
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(fileDownload.getByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is there a way for fo:external-graphic to accept these 2 different urls? Or is there something additional i need to do for it to work, since currently when the image comes from the webserver, the the resulting pdf file does not have the image in it, only a white space.

EDIT:
Here is the code that should make the XML to XSL to PDF:

```
 byte[] xsl = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/browserDocument.xsl"));
    byte[] xml = getBrowserDocument(filter, clientId, representId, ecatMain, showImage, language);
    InputStream inStr = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fop.xml");
    FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new java.net.URI("."), inStr);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);

    javax.xml.transform.Source xsltSrc = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xsl));

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSrc);

    String xmlStr = new String(xml, "UTF-8");
    xmlStr = xmlStr.replaceAll("<", "<");
    xmlStr = xmlStr.replaceAll(">", ">");

    javax.xml.transform.Source src = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

    transformer.transform(src, res);

    return out.toByteArray();
```

I keep getting error message in the log files:

```
2019-01-30 16:07:48.300 ERROR 8424 --- [https-jsse-nio-8087-exec-3] org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent          : Image not found. URI: https://localhost:4200/api/efront/secure/download/product/image/?fixedPrice=false&productId=2823&fileId=1756. (No context info available)
```

It seems like it is calling the URL, but it is not getting the actual image from it. Maybe some issue with the image headers or the FOUseragent is getting blocked?

Comment: Do you have any condition at xslt level, based on what you are passing url value to **fo:external-graphic** ?

Comment: mm... XSL just places the URL into the fo:external-graphic. What url to use is done inside the server before it reaches the part for xsl. defaultImageUrl comes from a model where the choise is already made.

Comment: Right. Then there is no change require at xslt level to these 2 urls to be accepted. What's the exception/validation bug are you facing here ?

Comment: if image comes from the webserver it is not shown on the resulting pdf document. I think the issue might actually be the &amp;

Comment: It might be the relative path issue. (Make sure the images exist in your webserver). Can you share your **FopFactory** code ?

Comment: @Vebbie edited question.

Comment: try this : `<fo:external-graphic src="url('{$ImagePath}')" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" width="100%"/>`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427499/image-not-found-for-background-image-attribute-of-block-container/54428956#54428956

Comment: @potame: If it's a recent version of Apache FOP, you don't have to put the image path inside url(...). (Though it isn't mentioned what version is being used)

Comment: Took a bit to find it. but v 2.1 is in use.

Comment: Resetting the image cache might help here. The image cache can be cleared like this: `fopFactory.getImageManager().getCache().clearCache();`

Comment: DIdnt help. Still only the images that are not from the webserver are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, implementing all above possible logic and seeing your code, I think `URIResolver` would help getting out of this as below:

Add it to your code : `fopFactory.setURIResolver(new ResolveURIForWebServer());`

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.URIResolver;

public class ResolveURIForWebServer implements URIResolver {

@Override
public Source resolve(String href, String baseURI) throws TransformerException {
    Source source = null;
    try {
        // CONVERT IMAGE TO INPUTSTREAM
        source = new StreamSource(InputStream);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {

    }
    return source;
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also it seems tobe causing a "java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: ..."

Comment: You can validate the certificate by following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore and if you can try again.

Comment: This thing didnt work out. so i took the longer route. Since the images are on the websever i wrote a piece of code that gets the file location in the filesystem and passes that to the xsl.